# Add multisite switch button. Click to switch to other page in same admin area

Tags: multisite, buttons

im new to this, so can anybody tell me how to get the active admin_url() of the page im currently on in a multisite wordpress backend.

I want to implement a button that goes from one backend to another multisites backend one with just clicking the button.